# Where does power/electricity come from in "Off to be a Wizard"

Tags: wizards

Where does the electrical power come from? For Example, how does Phillip power his Commodore 64 computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using magic you can change the "settings" on any object, including electronics and batteries. In this case, we can assume that they've hacked the Commodore to always have a full charge in the Power Supply Unit, negating the need for an external power source.

> ***They set the laptop’s battery to constantly be full, like Martin’s
> phone.** For internet access Martin simply used Wi-Fi to tether the
> laptop to his phone so he could access the phone’s 4G connection, a
> process that thoroughly confounded Phillip. Martin patiently talked
> Phillip through it as they went. He enjoyed playing teacher to
> Phillip’s student, instead of the other way around.*
>
> <sub><sup>Off To Be The Wizard: Chapter 18.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 4):

It has likely been hacked to not need power, or from the Commodore's perspective  to be plugged into an infinite source of power.